# display image on mouse over

Tags: jquery, css, rollover

What would be the easiest way to add a zoom icon to the top left of an image when you hover over the image.

All I am finding with rollovers is affecting the background image.

Ideally I would only make 1 zoom div and image

```
<div class="zoom"><img src="img/zoom_icon.png" /></div>
```

and clone that to any image inside a div called gallery

```
 <div class="gallery">
  <a href="#zoomed"><img src="img/hey.png" /></a>
 </div>
```

And use jquery with mouseover to get the zoom class and position it correctly:

```
display: block; position: relative; top:0; left:0
```

And when you mouseout to hide the zoom icon.

Hope this makes sense. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
var zoomIcon = $('<img src="path/to/zoom/icon.png" class="zoomIcon" />');
$('.zoom').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).append(zoomIcon);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.zoomIcon').remove();
    });
```

With CSS:

```
.gallery {
    position: relative;
}

.gallery > .zoomIcon {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.gallery:hover > .zoomIcon {
    display: block;
}
```

This requires the following mark-up, of course:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="path/to/zoom/icon.png" class="zoomIcon" />
    <!-- other content -->
</div>
```